# I get invalid argument error when running bitcoin-cli -getnetworkinfo, and a few other parameters

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

So I have bitcoind -daemon running and it appears to be generating the blockchain. keeps saying

> Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer...

The issue is I run bitcoin-cli commands and get the following error:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -getnetworkinfo
Error parsing command line arguments: Invalid parameter -getnetworkinfo
```

same for many others. The only cli command that seems to work is :

```
bitcoin-cli -getinfo
{
  "version": 180100,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 0,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 0,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1573696666,
  "keypoolsize": 1000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "warnings": ""
}
```

according to the manual they should all work but many are saying invalid argument. I have searched and am shocked that there does not appear to be any info on why this is happening to some and not others. So here I am.

Comment: It seems like if I remove the - in front of SOME of the parameters, they then work. Even though the instructions on bitcoin.org say to use the hypen (-) for all of them. Is this not strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getinfo` has been deprecated as an RPC command, and the hyphenated version is provided as a bridge for legacy applications that have not yet moved to `getblockchaininfo` and `getnetworkinfo`.

For regular RPC commands, you do not need the hyphen, and can simply run them as `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`.

The hyphenated parameters control the behaviour of bitcoin-cli itself, such as which `datadir` to connect to, or whether to use `named` parameters in the requests.

Comment: Thank you. At least there is a place on the internet, NOW,  for people to find this out, easily, cause I spent some time and found NOTHING that explained what you just did. :-) Thanks again.